# Bash script: Kill one process when other completes

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script to run one process after another approximately 1024 times with different command line options. However one of the processes include an infinite loop and I am trying to kill that process before another iteration of the loop begins.

So here is what I tried  so far (prog1 includes the infinite loop and I want to kill it when papi finishes running) :

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; i<32780; i+=32))
do
    ./prog1 $i &
    pid=$!;
    sleep 5s
    ./papi
    kill -s 2 $pid
done
```

However it does not kill any `prog1` instances, and of course it continues to create them at the beginning of each iteration. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does prog1 ignore signal 2?   Does it work if you use KILL?

Comment: Does the kill work from outside your script? Have you tried "kill -9"?

Comment: Why are you using SIGINT? The default for kill is SIGTERM, what happens if you use that?

Comment: Okay SIGTERM killed correctly.. I saw a lot of examples with SIGINT therefore I used it but I didn't think that is the source of the problem. If you could write an answer with this info I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It kills a process before finishing:

```
pkill $!
```

for example:

```
telnet 192.168.1.1  1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pkill $!
```